# Should I use a windows service?

Tags: windows, service

Hi I have a console app which I need to start up when Windows Server 2012 starts and without needing to login. I've done a bit of research and people advise a windows service is the correct approach, however the links are quite old and I wanted to confirm this is still the case, or indeed correct at all. Cheers.

Comment: If you need to perform some backgroundtasks and don't want to be affected by user logon/logoff, Windows service definitely suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows Service is still the most popular way to write and run servers and or a 'daemon' in Windows OS.

Depending on what your application is doing, you might have other options though, e.g. hosting an application in IIS (Microsoft's Web server application in Windows Server).

More recently, Microsoft has been working with Docker to also allow the use of containerized application deployments, which is available in new versions of Windows Server (Windows Server 2016).

Here are a few resources for more reading:

- For .NET developers: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Not just for .NET developers: [Quick Start: Windows Containers on Windows Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server)